# In Scheme how can I split an exact (rational) number into dividend and divisor?

Tags: math, numbers, scheme, r5rs, exact-match

The function I am looking for is something like:

```
(split 1/3) => (1 . 3)
(split 1093/209) => (1093 . 209)
```

Is it possible in RnRS, SRFI or any custom implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. To get the numerator and denominator of a rational number you have two procedures you can use:

```
(numerator (/ 6 4))    ⇒  3
(denominator (/ 6 4))  ⇒  2
```

As it demonstrates the values returned are the lowest terms. [The report](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.7.4.3) specifies the denominator is always positive and the denominator of 0 is defined to be 1.

There has been no change in this behavior for a long time. I see the same description in R3RS until the latest R7RS so you can expect it to exist in all implementations of Scheme that exists today.

Just for fun:

```
(define (split number)
  (cons (numerator number)
        (denominator number)))
```